# Get handle to WSGI app in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I need to close `pserve`/`waitress` process after forking, but I have trouble getting a reference to it so I could close it. Typically, in Pyramid `__init__.py` I do:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    ...
    config = Configurator(settings=settings,
                          authentication_policy=authn_policy,
                          authorization_policy=authz_policy,
                          root_factory=Root)
    config.scan()   
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

However, I can't store a variable with WSGI app somewhere because it's not visible in `globals()` in the app views, etc.

How I can get a handle to it or at least close it another way?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Configurator()` call seems to prevent adding keys to settings dictionary in main() function, so I used a trick with adding a dictionary under `settings['post_configurator_settings']` that can be used later, all of this in `__init__.py` of course:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
...
settings['post_configurator_settings'] = {}
config = Configurator(settings=settings,
                     ...
                      root_factory=Root)

...

wsgi_app = config.make_wsgi_app()
settings['post_configurator_settings']['wsgi_app'] = wsgi_app
return wsgi_app
```